# Background Changing and CSS with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the background of my website with every on-module load. It works perfectly without importing bootstrap, but once I try to import bootstrap it seems like
`$('html').css({"background":background})` is only effective on the parts that Twitter bootstrap is not used.

I feel like I should be changing the background only when Twitter bootstrap is imported.
Here a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztcx56p9b7twq8b/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-18%20at%203.35.21%20PM.png?m

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="/javascripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/background_decider.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>


  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">

         window.onload = function() {
           window.setTimeout(function () {
                var background = select_background();
                $('html').css({"background":background});
           }, 0);
           };


      </script>
    <div class="title">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don’t quite understand what your question is, or what behaviour you’re seeing. Are you saying that your `<html>` tag’s background doesn’t change?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that piece of code into ready() method, like this $(document).ready(function(){var background=select_background();
$('html').css({"background":background});});

Comment: I created a fiddle for you and it seems to work fine from there, FWIW: http://jsfiddle.net/CZgLW/

Comment: Also, try adding an alert (or stepping into your code) into your select_background method. It could be that for some reason the handler isn't getting added until after the window has loaded, or that select_background isn't loaded yet.

Comment: Maybe I couldn't fully describe my problem. this is the kind of behavior I get https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztcx56p9b7twq8b/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-18%20at%203.35.21%20PM.png?m

Comment: Oh. So it's almost like something is over top of the background image. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an element is covering up part of your page. Without seeing your complete HTML/CSS it's hard to tell what that is. But, here's where I would start:

1. Use FireBug (in FireFox) or the Developer Tools (in Chrome: Ctrl+Shift+J, IE: F12) to select the element for determining what it is.
2. Add the code below to your CSS file. It makes sure the element that uses it has no background.
3. Add `class="transparent"` to the element from step 1.

.

```
.transparent
{
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, but this is how I fixed my problem:

I changed $('html').css({"background":background}); to $('body').css({"background":background});